# formatting issue when having decimal numbers as file names

Tags: string-manipulation

so basically I'm trying to generate a list of file names. What I have done so far is the following:

```
total = Table[StringTemplate["/home/Projekt/output/b12_t`t`_a`a`.csv"]@<|
"t" -> 0.01 k, "a" -> 0.01 l|>, {k, 1, 21}, {l, 0, 50}]
```

Then I realized that, the mantissa ended with `0`s are not displayed in full decimal place.
For example: instead of showing

```
 /home/Projekt/output/b12_t0.01_a0.00.csv
```

it shows

```
 /home/Project/output/b12_t0.01_a0.csv
```

I know that normally we can use `Precision[x]` to print the exact number but in this case is does no help. Much appreciated if someone can give me a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Table[
  StringTemplate[
     "`t`", InsertionFunction -> (ToString@NumberForm[#, {1, 2}] &)
  ]@<|"t" -> 0.01 k|>,
  {k, 0, 10}
]
```

> ```
> {"0.00", "0.01", "0.02", "0.03", "0.04", "0.05", "0.06", "0.07", "0.08", "0.09", "0.10"}
> ```